# Saving live video streams

Tags: video-streaming

Can anyone suggest software to download / grab live video streams from Ustream, Youtube etc. as they are streaming live?

Video downloading tools do not work with live streams.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recording a YouTube live stream using VLC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599388/recording-a-youtube-live-stream-using-vlc)

Answer (score 0):

`rtmpdump` can capture live and not live rtmp streams well (plain rtmp and encrypted sessions too). But it looks like youtube is not using rtmp flash  streamin for their live broadcasts. Instead they come up with some other idea.

Check out [Stefan Sundin's](http://stefansundin.com/blog/452) instructions on how to capture youtube live streams.

For Ustream rtmpdump should work. Helper scripts and instructions for Ustream can be found [here](http://www.tech-juice.org/2012/05/20/how-to-play-ustream-channels-in-vlc/) or [here](https://gist.github.com/fuba/634461).

Comment: Thank you,falconer! I am not really that tech-savvy. I start to fail to understand Stefan Sundin's instructions from the third paragraph: I don't have a "favorite browser’s network monitor" and so on. As far as I understand there is no easy (preferably GUI) way to download Youtube live streams?

Comment: Yes, or at least I don't know any easy (GUI) way. But maybe someone else knows.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just record it from your screen with SimpleScreenRecorder or something. Although it means you have to watch it on your screen as it goes on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) with fire fox.
if you are on windows you can install Internet Download Manager.