# Recording a YouTube live stream using VLC

Tags: video, cron, vlc, streaming, video-recording

I'm trying to set VLC to record a live stream on YouTube using cron.  Vlc records videos that aren't live streaming just fine, but when the stream is live VLC records at most only 24 seconds.  Why does it stop there?  How can I get it to record more?

The lines I have in my crontab file were adapted from [the answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574097/schedule-to-record-video-stream-in-vlc):

```
35 21 20 3 * cvlc --sout file/ts:/path/to/directory/file.mp4 <link to video>
37 21 20 3 * sh -c "killall cvlc; killall vlc"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For livestreams I would recommend using [livestreamer](https://github.com/chrippa/livestreamer) instead of VLC. Recording with `livestreamer` is a breeze, e.g.:

```
livestreamer <livestream-url> best -o vod.mp4
```

livestreamer supports [dozens of different](http://docs.livestreamer.io/plugin_matrix.html) streaming providers and works very reliably, even with spotty streams.

For installation instructions check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/414209/81372) by [@henry](https://askubuntu.com/users/125988/henry).

Comment: livestreamer is now deprecated and forked to streamlink.

Answer (score 0):

According to livestreamer manpage, options must come first:

```
COMMAND-LINE USAGE
$ livestreamer [OPTIONS] [URL] [STREAM]
```

These will show you streams you can choose from:

```
$ livestreamer [URL]
```

or

```
$ livestreamer [OPTIONS] [URL]
```

This will save the best quality available stream to file arq.mp4 in the current dir:

```
livestreamer -o arq.mp4 <livestream-url> best
```

Check

```
$ man livestreamer
```

for many more details.

Answer (score 0):

### [Streamlink](https://streamlink.github.io/)

[livestreamer](https://github.com/chrippa/livestreamer) is no longer maintained. Use [Streamlink](https://streamlink.github.io/) instead

Install ([`install --upgrade` to upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10440459/4970442)):

```
sudo -H pip install streamlink
```

Then just

```
streamlink --output stream.mp4 "https://www.youtube.com/freecodecamp/live" best # or worst
```

You can also send the stream to `cvlc` with any parameter you may want